# RSS-Feed Webpart SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rss

I had added a RSS-Feed WebPart to my SharePoint Site. Sometimes this Webpart displays the error message: "The requested RSS feed could not be displayed. Please verify the settings and url for this feed. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator." This problem is on multiple clients and only sporadic. The RSS Feed is from a News Site and permanently available. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to debug this problem by asking your users who are facing this problem to directly access the feed URL in their browsers and see if the problem is not with their client machine configurations

Comment: The URL to the RSS-Feed is OK. This was my first check. But thanks for your answer

Comment: did you check the sharepoint logs and did you get anything thier additionally you can go through the following post http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/85b0a013-8f6c-49e1-b884-c2400d2ee522